# Detect if value is contained in a row

Tags: php, mysql

Basically I have a table like this:

```
|id|username|password|email|hasAlphaKey|
 1  test1    test2    -----      1
 2  test2    test3    -----      0
```

and I want to detect if the `hasAlphaKey == 1` How can I achieve this?

I tried doing this way:

```
$hasAlphaKey = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE hasAlphaKey='1'");
$check_for_key = mysql_num_rows($hasAlphaKey);

if($check_for_key == 1) {
  echo 'You have an alpha key!';
}
```

If works with Account *test1* cause it has the value 1 in `hasAlphaKey`
But when I login to `test2` it still does the line `echo 'You have an alpha key!';` but the value is set to zero?

May I have some assistance? :)

Comment: while using what query, `SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE hasAlphaKey='1'` or `SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE hasAlphaKey='0'`? you'd be best to another clause to it, for "username".

Comment: I'll try `SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE hasAlphaKey='0'` I'll get back to you in a few moments.

Comment: your present query using num_rows will return true, because a row exists.

Comment: @Fred-ii- it now doesn't echo on both accounts including `test1` which has the value 1 set.

Comment: doing `WHERE hasAlphaKey='1' AND username='test2'` will return false. Doing `WHERE hasAlphaKey='0' AND username='test2'` will return true. and changing `if($check_for_key == 1)` to `if($check_for_key >0)`

Comment: Oh okay. So I have to just alter my query and it should work?

Comment: @GabrielFraser whats the data type of hasAlphaKey?

Comment: so... my comment above, how that work out? should have worked. [**mainly this one...**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31576828/detect-if-value-is-contained-in-a-row#comment51108198_31576828)

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work @Fred-ii-

Comment: what is the column type for `hasAlphaKey`?

Comment: The column type for `hasAlphaKey` is INT if thats what you're asking?

Comment: then why the string comrade ?

Comment: you need to remove the quotes around the `'1'` it's treated as a string literal, rather than an integer.

Comment: It's an integer column?

Comment: When I remove the '' It still doesn't execute `echo 'You have an alpha key!';`

Comment: your where clause as NANDA answered could care less what user you are logged into, Mr. McGoo or Santa. the # of rows is still 1

Comment: Okay so I found something interesting. It's not reading from a certain row where the username is contained. It's reading from the whole mysql table.

Comment: no kidding look at your where clause !

Comment: @Fred-ii- I forgot to tag you.

Comment: @DrewPierce could you suggest the query I should use?

Comment: let's jump down to Nanda's answer. he deserves the points, k ?

Comment: Well. I've tried that and it still is reading from the ***whole*** table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
|id|username|password|email|hasAlphaKey|
 1  test1    test2    -----      1
 2  test2    test3    -----      0


$qry="SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE hasAlphaKey=1 AND username='test2'";
$result123 = mysql_query($qry);
$check_for_key = mysql_num_rows($result123);

if($check_for_key == 1) {
  echo 'You have an alpha key!';
}
```

For username='test1' it should echo.

For username='test2' it should not echo

Comment: if you say test2 **echos**, then i would assume you have more than 1 row for test2 !

Comment: Dude. I think you explaining it like this really helped! tbh I have no idea what you did but it works! You're magician! Thanks to everyone who tried to help! :)

Comment: i know nothing about php btw, well, at least compared to Fred

Comment: I've just gotta make it detect the username now. :s

Answer (score 1):

`test1` has alpha key, `test2` does not. So in the table there are 1 elements with alpha key. The code is working as expected. Maybe you wanted to do this

```
SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE hasAlphaKey=1 AND username='test2'
```

Comment: I'm with you Nanda I think they are focusing on the non-obvious

Comment: so if you run this Query from Nanda, he was suggesting that you might have a simple solution

Comment: I've tried this and it still echo's on the user `test2` :l

Answer (score 0):

```
$hasAlphaKey = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Accounts");
$check_for_key = mysql_num_rows($hasAlphaKey);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($hasAlphaKey);
$hasKey = $row['hasAlphaKey'];
if($hasKey == 1) {
     echo 'You have an alpha key!';
}
```